# 3D Printer makes steps at Y axis (in some cases)

Tags: print-quality, y-axis

I have bought the *Tevo Tarantula 3D Printer Kit*.

When I'm printing something that I created (using Cinema 4D), the printer prints it without any problems, but, when I download something from the internet, my Y axis makes steps 1-3 mm per layer and it makes any product unusable at the end.

This is what is does.

[image: Failed print]

It does every single layer, not just randomly. I don't know if I have bad configuration or something like that.

Comment: I assume you use a slicer like Cura. Is there anything visible in the slicer? Since the model is completely proceeded there should be no impact of the source and style of the stl file on the gcode.

Comment: Also a photo is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Y-Axis is Heating bed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D Printing.SE! With this amount of information it is really hard to troubleshoot for others. Maybe you can specify (in the question) how you download things and what you do with these models to generate G-code files, as in this last step you define the instructions for the printer.

Comment: Hi Lopolo! As @0scar implies, we need a comparison of, or you need to compare, a g-code file that works, and one that doesn't. What are you downloading, an `.stl` file presumably? What do you then do, and use, to create the G-code? Please edit your question and provide *detailed steps* (with examples/links?) of what you are doing.  Also, as Klaus has stated, a couple of photos of a good print and a bad print might be useful. The more information that you provide, the easier it will be to answer your question. :-)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `Y axis makes steps 1-3 mm per layer` and your comment `Y-axis is Heating bed`? It is a little unclear (that is why a photo would be useful). `per layer` implies the Z-axis. The heating bed is both in the plane of the X and Y axes. But the X-axis is really the print gantry, across the printer. Do you mean that the 1-3 mm steps occur in the Y axis, i.e. the direction coming out towards you, as the print bed moves? and that they occur in *every* layer? I presume that is what you mean

Comment: I will add some photos when ill be home.

Comment: duplicate of https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/475 I suspect.

Comment: Reading it closely this could be layer shifting, e.g. https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0714/6487/files/DSC01220_x500.png

Comment: This is what is does. https://imgur.com/47cvqZm It does every single layer, not just randomly. I dont know if i have bad configuration or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the image. Next time please edit your question, and post the image (and any additional information) in the question, not in the comments. That way, all of the information is in one block and people don't have to read the comments to get all of the information. Comments are used for clarification demands. I have edited your question for you this time. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4):

When you describe a problem like this, it is best to describe the effect, not what you think is the cause - particularly since others then might mis-read your description.

Each layer being offset in one direction suggests that there is a problem with either the part moving on the bed (unlikely), or in the registration of one axis drifting over time.

Most likely, your Y-axis is skipping steps. It could be several things:

- the axis binding on it's runners
- the drive belt skipping because it is loose
- the drive belt binding because it is too tight
- too fast a print/travel speed
- the print nozzle catching on the print (bed too high, no z-hop)
- not enough drive current to the stepper motor
- stepper motor failing
- belt drive loose on the stepper shaft

A common 'feature' of 3d printing is that different models might emphasise one problem, but a different shape might hide it.

Check that everything is properly tightened, moves freely, and the belts are undamaged - with luck you can find the problem and it's not electrical.

Comment: Seems you are right. See the image OP has provided.