# Issues with my print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3, print-failure

I am currently making an ironman helmet but running into a couple problems.

Whenever I start my print it starts off fine, but then after it builds the bottom support and starts on the build itself things get really wonky. It seems that the build gradually builds away from the support and starts to float in the air.

I also see an issue where the model starts to curve and the filament isn't sticking to the support instead it makes a straight line through the curve.

Lastly the support column on the bottom left starts to clump up.

I am using an Ender 3 printer and Cura.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing layer shifting, please check the tension of the X-axis belt, driver current.

---

*A more elaborated answer is found [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/500).*

Comment: if it's starting to float, wouldn't that be pointing at the z-axis?

Comment: Awesome! This answers all my questions. I saw that this could be several different things, so ill do a few things and see what i can do to fix it! Thanks!